# After update to Xamarin.Forms 5, App crashes with Shell error

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, mobile, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Finally I decided update my app to new `Xamarin.Forms 5` ... but after solving few issue with build and running application it crashes with error:

```
IsTransient: Exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' was thrown
Message: No Content found for ShellContent, Title:New Contact, Route D_FAULT_ShellContent16
TargetSite: Xamarin.Forms.IShellContentController.GetOrCreateContent
```

Have anybody faced with the same issue ?

Comment: Where you're getting this error ? Are you implemented Shell on your project ?

Comment: I have this error at startup ... Yes I have Shell in my project, but previously it worked, I've only updated Xamarin.Forms 5

Comment: Did you check the breaking changes for version 5 ?

Comment: Yes, but I did not found something related ContentTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue happens, because Xamarin.Forms 5 does not allow not set `ContentTemplate` for `FlyoutItem`